# Carousel bootstrap with vue js component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

currently I'm creatting  one component using Carousel With indicators  [GetBootstrap Carousel With indicators](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators) 
I am implementing this code in one vue component, like:

```
<template>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" :data-slide-to="index" :class=" index === 0? 'active' : '' "></li>
            </div>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
                <div :class=" index === 0? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item' ">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" :src="image.path" :alt="image.name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["app_route"],
        data() {
            return {
                images: [],
            };
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.getItemsSlider();
        },
        methods: {
            getItemsSlider() {
                axios
                    .get(this.app_route + "/admin/slider/list", {
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        //console.log("response: ", response.data);
                        this.images = response.data;
                    });
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

[image]

currently the first image is showing but the other images are not showing, the slider is not working too.

Why? what I'm doing wrong?

here is the code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-snow-28xqe?file=/public/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/), there must be strictly nesting of elements `.carousel-inner > .carousel-item`.

You should try this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" :class="index === 0 ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item'">
      <img class="d-block w-100" :src="image" :alt="image.name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes! it's work!!! thanks you so much!!